# JdbcRealm, DatasourceRealm and JaasRealm

Tags: java, security, java-ee-6, jaas

I'm working on a Jboss AS7 server, and I'm stuck with a security decision.
What are the differences (and advantages) of these security realm in Java EE6 : [JdbcReal](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JDBCRealm.html), [DatasourceRealm](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/DataSourceRealm.html) and [JaasRealm](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JAASRealm.html) ?

I used a DatasourceRealm with Glassfish, using the web management console, and that was pretty easy, but I can't find such feature with JBoss.

On the other hand, JAASRealm looks at first sight very complicated.

The second question is : where could I find some **good and clear** tutorials to explain Jaas security ?